# Android Java Application is freezing with No Error message being sent back

Tags: java, android

for some Reason my Android Java App is freezing when i press a certain button. However the app doesnt seem to be crashing since no error message is send back to Android Studio. It just freezes and after a while the app will restart.

Here is the Code that is executed on ButtonClick. I am aware that this is very confusing because  i am using so many variables :/ i will try to put some declaration above the actualy Button Code.

```
ChronometerList = new Chronometer[]{Overtime1,Overtime2,Overtime3,Overtime4,Overtime5,Overtime6,Overtime7,Overtime8,Overtime9,Overtime10,Overtime11,Overtime12};
 //is an Array of Chronometers

    TimeList = new TextView[]{ TimeUntilTopic1Ends,TimeUntilTopic2Ends,TimeUntilTopic3Ends,TimeUntilTopic4Ends,TimeUntilTopic5Ends,TimeUntilTopic6Ends,TimeUntilTopic7Ends,TimeUntilTopic8Ends,TimeUntilTopic9Ends,TimeUntilTopic10Ends,TimeUntilTopic11Ends,TimeUntilTopic12Ends}; 
    // Array of Textviews, that show us the Time Left, i need so many since i build a table out of lines and every line needs a timer

    TopicTimer = new MyCounter[]{TopicTimer1,TopicTimer2,TopicTimer3,TopicTimer4,TopicTimer5,TopicTimer6,TopicTimer7,TopicTimer8,TopicTimer9,TopicTimer10,TopicTimer11,TopicTimer12};
```

// MyCounter is extended by Countdowntimer -> Simple Class
//All the Timer are being build fine with no error

Here is the Code. Hella confusing but i hope you can help anyways :D

```
  NextTopic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO For some Reason this freezes the Whole Program
           if(TimeList[row-1].getText().toString() == "Done")
           {
               ChronometerList[row-1].stop();
               long ElapsedTimeInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - ChronometerList[row-1].getBase();
               int RowUsed = 0;
               int n = 0;
               while(TimeList[row].getText()!= "null")
               {
                    RowUsed++;
               }

              if(RowUsed != 0) {
                  int ElapsedTime = (int) (long) ElapsedTimeInMillis;
                  double SubtractionTime = ElapsedTime / RowUsed;

                  while (RowUsed >= n) {
                      TimeList[row + n].setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(TimeList[row + n].getText().toString()) - SubtractionTime));
                      n++;
                  }
                  row++;
                  TopicTimer[row-1].start();
              }
              else
              {
                //nothing yet

              }


           }
           else
           {


               int RowsLeft = 0;
               int n = 0;
               while(TimeList[row].getText()!= null)
               {
                   RowsLeft++;
               }
            // have to split up the text in there cause there are **m **s in it and not just the number
            String TimeOutput = TimeList[row - 1].getText().toString();
            String[] TimePartSeconds = TimeOutput.split("m ");
            String Minutes = TimePartSeconds[0];
            String SecondsLetters = TimePartSeconds[1];
            String[] GetSeconds = SecondsLetters.split("s");
               String seconds = GetSeconds[0];


            int SecondsLeft = (Integer.valueOf(Minutes)*60) +(Integer.valueOf(seconds));
            long AdditionTimeSeconds = SecondsLeft/RowsLeft;

            TopicTimer[row-1].onFinish();


            while (RowsLeft>= n) {
                   TimeList[row + n].setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(TimeList[row - 1 + n].getText().toString()) + (AdditionTimeSeconds/60)));
                   n++;
               }
              row++;
              TopicTimer[row-1].start();
           }
       }
   });
```

Comment: This loop, `while(TimeList[row].getText()!= "null")
               {
                    RowUsed++;
               }` will never exit.   What are you trying to do?   Plus, you cannot compare strings using `!=`.  Please understand that strings are objects, not primitives.  Read about comparing strings in Java.  Finally, your code would a LOT easier to read if you used proper Java naming conventions.

Comment: The While loop will check the text of every TimeUntilTopicXEnds until there is nothing written into it which i expressed with null cause there was never a text applied to them if not chosen too. That way i can figure out how many rows are left in the table until the end-> strored in Rows Used. I dont know about those Conventions i guess i should read :O. One of those people that writes code and doesnt read so much about it :/ --> But i mean if a TextView has no text written in it TextView.getText should be null right?

Comment: Is this running in an AsyncTask?

Comment: Please read that loop carefully.  As I say, it will never exit since `row` will always have the same value.  And you **cannot compare strings using !=** Voting to close since you are not listening.

Comment: Considering i have  no clue what an AsyncTask is i am gonna say now. Its a simpe onClickListener in a method called ButtonFunctionality() that is being called from onCreate(). I also have a start and stop button in there that work fine.

Comment: Oh my God you are right :/.... int RowsLeft = 0;
                   int n = 0;
                   while(TimeList[row+RowsLeft].getText()!= null)
                   {
                       RowsLeft++;
                   }        //That should solve the the loop issue right ?

Comment: Nope, **because you cannot compare strings using !=**